# How to install an action filter in all actions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, action-filter

Is there a way to have an action filter, like

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    ...
```

be automatically applied to all actions in a web site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is an out-of-the-box way to do this.  The easiest thing to do for simple sites is just apply the filter at the Controller level.  This is pretty common, and generally it's a good idea to have your own base controller class in case things like this crop up where you want to propagate it to all your controllers.  E.g.:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
  ...
}

public class HomeController : MyBaseController
{
  ...
}
```

That being said, [here is a blog post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/06/24/Application-wide-action-filters-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) showing how you can achieve application wide action filters.  Looks like a small amount of work, but perhaps you can use this technique.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but starting with ASP.NET MVC 3 you can use [global filters](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

1. You can apply it to an entire controller class to have it affect all actions on a controller.
2. You can apply it to a base controller class and have all your controllers inherit from that controller, thus getting the effect of applying the filter to all controllers.
3. You can use a base controller class and override the OnActionExecuting method directly on the controller which is probably more appropriate than using a filter if your intent is to apply your filter code on all actions across the board.

Comment: By two, you mean applying it to the Controller class provided by ASP.NET MVC? Is that possible? How?

Comment: No, he means that all of your controllers should inherit from a base controller class that you would write, which extended the asp.net mvc controller.  On your base controller class, you would tag it with the filter.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use ActionFilters, as pointed out by Victor, in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   // Register global filter
   GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

Or in AspNetCore you could try

```
  services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
    options.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilterAttribute());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where NewlyCreatedActionFilter is the ActionFilter you're creating, obviously. :)

```
[NewlyCreatedActionFilter]
public class Basecontroller : Controller
{
  ...
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
  ...
}

public class AccountController : BaseController
{
  ...
}
```

Both of these controller classes would inherit from BaseController, so the NewlyCreatedActionFilter filter is applied to all.