# Validate ModelState.IsValid globally for all controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core Controllers I always check if the ModelState is valid:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff([FromBody]DoStuffRequest request)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return BadRequest("invalid parameters");
  }
  else
  {
    return Ok("some data"));
  }
}
```

Is there a way to check validity of the ModelState globally using a filter so I don't have to do this in every API item in every controller again? It would be nice if the action could rely on the modelstate being valid and not needing to check:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff([FromBody]DoStuffRequest request)
{
  return Ok("some data"));
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [`ActionFilter`](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). It's not globally, but it moves the problem from your method body into an attribute. I realize that it doesn't solve your problem completely, but it might be better than nothing.

```
public class ModelStateValidationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                 .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ModelStateValidationActionFilter]
public IHttpActionResult Post(object model)
{

}
```

I believe that you can set it on your controller as well. I haven't actually tried that, but [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320757/how-to-install-an-action-filter-in-all-actions-in-asp-net-mvc) it could work.

```
[ModelStateValidationActionFilter]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{

}
```

**EDIT:**

As [@Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932049/camilo-terevinto) mentioned it is a bit different for Core. Just use this `ActionFilter` if you want to use Core.

```
public class ModelStateValidationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {    
        var modelState = context.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
            context.Result = new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = "Modelstate not valid",
                StatusCode = 400
            };
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ApiController` is from Web Api 2, it does not exist anymore in ASP.NET Core. Besides this, you should not append to your filters `ActionFilterAttribute` rather just `Attribute`. Even more intent would be `ValidateModelStateAttribute`

Comment: Also, action filters can be registered globally in `Startup`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, yes, you're right. I missed the Core part. I've updated my answer with a proper ActionFilterAttribute that will work with Core.

Comment: Why do you call base.OnActionExecuting(context) twice in your sample code?

Comment: ok - but in ASp.Net Core your code does not even compile anyway :)

Comment: @Sam - The last edit is from a Core project I have right now. It compiles. What error are you getting? Just make sure to import `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters`

Comment: Aah, sorry, I derived from a different class, my mistake!

Answer (score 19):

As a followup to this: in ASP.NET Core 2.1, there is a controller attribute called `[ApiController]`. If you include that attribute, it automatically uses a built-in `ActionFilter` called `ModelStateInvalidFilter`, meaning any custom action filter that checks ModelState will never be reached since the `[ApiController]` attribute already registers its own filter.

To suppress the behavior, the current documents give this option:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
   options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; // This is the setting
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The existing answers so far are for **ASP.NET Web API** and not for **ASP.NET Core**. The actual way to do it in ASP.NET Core is:

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

And you can register this filter globally in **Startup.cs**, so this will execute in every single call and you do not have to repeat it in every Action/Controller:

```
options.Filters.Add(typeof(SampleActionFilter));
```

See more [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).

Answer (score 7):

For ASP.NET Core 2.0, to avoid applying attributes to all `Controllers` or `Actions` individually;

Define a filter:

```
namespace Test
{
    public sealed class ModelStateCheckFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Startup.cs`, add it as filter:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new ModelStateCheckFilter());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [HandleInvalidModelState](https://github.com/tchelidze/HandleInvalidModelState)

`PM> Install-Package HandleInvalidModelState`

example

```
[HttpPost]
[TypeFilter(typeof(HandleInvalidModelWithViewActionFilterAttribute))]
public IHttpActionResult Post(object model)
{}
```

Besides basic cases scenario (returning view with invalid model) package supports returning [Json](https://github.com/tchelidze/HandleInvalidModelState/wiki/Handle-with-Json) and [Redirection](https://github.com/tchelidze/HandleInvalidModelState/wiki/Handle-with-Redirect) of request.

*disclaimer : author of the package*

Answer (score 0):

For `async` methods the filter has to implement `IAsyncActionFilter`. I have put together this filter, which:

- does nothing if the ModelState is valid

OR

- sets the Result to BadRequestObjectResult with some details about what failed
- logs the ModelState with more details

---

```
public class ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage?view=aspnetcore-2.1
    private static readonly Action<ILogger, IList<(string Key, string ErrorMessage, string ExceptionMessage)>, Exception> ModelStateLoggerAction;

    private readonly ILogger<ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter> logger;

    static ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter()
    {
        ModelStateLoggerAction = LoggerMessage.Define<IList<(string Key, string ErrorMessage, string ExceptionMessage)>>(LogLevel.Warning, new EventId(1, nameof(ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter)), "{ModelState}");
    }

    public ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter(ILogger<ValidModelStateAsyncActionFilter> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
            await next();

        this.LogModelState(context);

        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(GetErrorResponse(context));
    }

    private static ErrorResponse GetErrorResponse(ActionContext context)
    {
        return new ErrorResponse
        {
            ErrorType = ErrorTypeEnum.ValidationError,
            Message = "The input parematers are invalid.",
            Errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                .ToList()
        };
    }

    private void LogModelState(ActionContext context)
    {
        // credit: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/
        var items = from ms in context.ModelState
                    where ms.Value.Errors.Any()
                    let fieldKey = ms.Key
                    let errors = ms.Value.Errors
                    from error in errors
                    select (Key: fieldKey, ErrorMessage: error.ErrorMessage, ExceptionMessage: error.Exception.Message);

        ModelStateLoggerAction(this.logger, items.ToList(), null);
    }
}
```